# Add extension to a list of files

Tags: files, perl, rename

I am trying to determine a perl method to add an extension to a list of files. I can already rename a list of files with a certain extension to some other extension, but I need to be able to do this for any file name, whether or not it already has an extension.

For example, I have a list of files such as:

```
file1
file2
file3
ps.dir
```

And I want to rename them ALL to `filename.extension`:

```
file1.bad
file2.bad
file3.bad
ps.dir.bad
```

Answer (score 4):

At the shell, if you've got the Perl `rename` installed (sometimes called `prename`):

```
rename -v 's/$/.bad/' *
```

If you have too many files for the shell `*` glob to handle them all you can mix'n'match with `find` like this (also replace `+` with `\;` if necessary):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec rename -v 's/$/.bad/' {} +
```

For Perl, just use `move` from a standard module:

```
use File::Copy;
for (<*>) { move($_, "$_.bad"); }
```

Comment: oh yeah. `find`. duh. way better than my ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no spaces in the file names:

```
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file}.bad"; done
```

Comment: This will work with spaces, It even works with newlines.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ ! . -sf / ] &&
mkdir ../bad  &&
pax  -rwls/$/.bad/ . ../bad
```

That will create a hardlink mirror of `.` in `../bad`. Every file rooted in `.` will afterward also be found in `../bad` but by a name with the appendix `.bad`. If the new tree satisfies, remove the current tree and `mv` the `../bad` tree over it.